# Flipping a coing probability

Tags: probability

Given that we have already tossed a balanced coin ten times and obtained zero heads, what is
the probability that we must toss it at least two more times to obtain the first head?

One thing I know is that tossing it initially 10 times is of no use for the answer. However, how can I give an exact value when the first head could come 2+n time? Where n could be [0, infinity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equal to the Probability of getting no heads in the first toss. This can be formed as an infinite series as $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}\dots=1-\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 4):

It is $1$ minus the probability of a head in one toss. As you pointed out, the $10$ unsuccessful tosses are irrelevant, the coin is balanced.

Comment: Haha, the complement. Its been a long day. Thanks you!